# How to check if a table exists in Hive?

Tags: sql, odbc, hive

I am connecting to Hive via an ODBC driver from a .NET application. Is there a query to determine if a table already exists?

For example, in MSSQL you can query the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` table and in Netezza you can query the `_v_table` table.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you done any research?

Comment: Yes I have done research and come up with nothing. The only solution I can come up with is to attempt to select from the table and catch the exception.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two approaches by which you can check that:

1.) As @dimamah suggested, just to add one point here, for this approach you need to

```
 1.1) start the **hiveserver** before running the query
 1.2) you have to run two queries
      1.2.1) USE <database_name>
      1.2.2) SHOW TABLES LIKE 'table_name'
      1.2.3) Then you check your result using Result set.
```

2.) Second approach is to use HiveMetastoreClient APIs, where you can directly use the APIs to check whether the **table_name** exist in a particular **database** or not.

For further help please go through this [Hive 11](http://hive.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/HiveMetaStoreClient.html)

Comment: The link for "Hive 11" is now broken (404 Not Found).  Do you know where is the updated location of the said documentation?  I also looked at this doc but seems the info there is limited: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+APIs+Overview#HiveAPIsOverview-Metastore(Java)

Answer (score 16):

Execute the following command : `show tables in DB like 'TABLENAME'`
If the table exists, its name will be returned, otherwise nothing will be returned.
This is done directly from hive. for more options see [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ShowTables/Partitions/Indexes).

`DB` is the database in which you want to see if the table exists.
`TABLENAME` is the table name you seek,

What actually happens is that Hive queries its [metastore](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties) (depends on your configuration but it can be in a standard RDBMS like MySQL) so you can optionally connect directly to the same metastore and write your own query to see if the table exists.

Answer (score 12):

When programming on Hive by Spark SQL, you can use following method to check whether Hive table exists.

```
if (hiveContext.hql("SHOW TABLES LIKE '" + tableName + "'").count() == 1) {
    println(tableName + " exists")
}
```

Comment: Spark is depreciating hql... will this solution be guaranteed to work using a regular hive context with SQL?  Is there a more general Spark method for looking at Hive meta-information, other than running a query?

Comment: Also -- using Spark 1.3.0, I get the following error:  "  User class threw exception: [1.13] failure: ``in'' expected but identifier like found
show tables like 'sample_table_name';   "  I also get this error when I do include "in <schemaname>" before the table name

Comment: Spark 1.5. Works with sparkContext too, not just Hive Context.  table_exists = len(sqlCtx.sql("SHOW TABLES IN "+ stg_db).filter("tableName='%s'" % stg_tab).collect()) == 1

Comment: In Spark 2+ we can use `sparkSession.sqlContext.tableNames(databaseName="default")` to get the list of tables in a given db_schema

Answer (score 9):

If someone is using shell script like me then my answer could be useful. Assume that your table is in the default namespace.

```
table=your_hive_table
validateTable=$(hive --database default -e "SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table'")
if [[ -z $validateTable ]]; then
  echo "Error:: $table cannot be found"
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Due to HIVE-4364 bug this doesn't work with beeline unforunatally, +1 anyway.

Comment: Beeline -> https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/How-to-check-the-existence-of-the-table-in-Beeline-Hive/m-p/181220/highlight/true#M143449

Comment: Note: for exact table match -> grep -w instead of grep should be used in the link above.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using SparkSQL you can do the following.

```
if "table_name" in sqlContext.tableNames("db_name"):
    ...do something
```

http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SQLContext.tableNames

Answer (score 3):

Code similar to below one can find in many of my Spark notebooks:

```
stg_table_exists = sqlCtx.sql("SHOW TABLES IN "+ stg_db) 
                  .filter("tableName='%s'" % stg_tab_name) .collect()
```

(made two-liner for readability)

I wish Spark would have an API call to check the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a scala spark app and SparkSQL you can do the following

```
if spark.catalog.tableExists("tablename") {do something}
```