# What is the best way to check existence of Hive table?

Tags: hive

Options in my mind:

1. Fire `DESCRIBE TABLE;`
2. Fire `SELECT 1 FROM TABLE;`

These queries will fail if table does not exist.

Which is better way? Or is there any other good approach?

Comment: `SHOW TABLES LIKE 'table_name'` See http://stackoverflow.com/a/21218353/3365426

Comment: You could always check the hive metastore TBLS table for the existence of a table.

Answer (score 0):

In many scenarios, we might not be sure in which database the table exists, so generally we keep looping through all the databases. To save time, you can use the below script.
replace the $BEELINE_CONN_STRING with your beeline strings, you can save this as a script and pass table_name as parameter. To make your searching specific to some databases you can also change the `show databases` to `show database like <your preferred database string>` in the below code or pass that also as a parameter to the script.

```
table_name=${1}
for database in `$BEELINE_CONN_STRING --showHeader=false --outputformat=tsv2 --silent=true -e "show databases;" 2> /dev/null `
do
result=`$BEELINE_CONN_STRING --silent=true --showHeader=false --outputformat=tsv2 -e "use $database;show tables like '*$table_name*';"  2> /dev/null `
if [[ "test_append"$result"" != "test_append" ]];
then
    echo "Table $result exists in $database"
else
    echo "Table not found in $database"
fi
done
```

Sample output looks like

```
Table not found in yourdb
Table www_table exists in mydb
```